# Set minimum confidence to ocr in Matlab

Tags: matlab, ocr, text-extraction, matlab-cvst, confidence-interval

My Matlab program for extracting text using ocr function gives many false positives which having lower confidence. Is there any way to set `ocrtxt.WordConfidence` to a minimum value and ignore all lower values? I want `ocrtxt.Words` or `ocrtxt.Text` only above confidence 0.8 for further process.

```
ocrtxt = ocr(regionFilteredTextMask);
ocrtxt.Text;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to create a logical index based on your threshold value:

```
bestWordsIdx = ocrtxt.WordConfidence > 0.8;
bestWords = ocrtxt.Words(bestWordsIdx)
```

And same for Text:

```
bestTextIdx = ocrtxt.CharacterConfidence > 0.8
bestText = ocrtxt.Text(bestTextIdx)
```